# polymer serve --open does not refresh browser with changes after edits

Tags: google-chrome, caching, polymer-starter-kit

FYI, I have resolved this problem but I don't understand why it works. please give me some hints. Issue is both on MAC and WINDOWS. extremely annoying. resolved on WIN by DL CHROME CANARY browser.  I believe issue is caching.

I init a new Polymer starter-kit

```
polymer init starter-kit.
```

I make a couple of edits to prove that I can update pages.
The updates work on CHROME CANARY, But all other browsers the changes are not rendered.  WHY not other browsers?

I believe that CANARY does not cache code. Other BROWSERS do.  Is there a way to disable cache on FIREFOX, CHROME, SAFARI so that I can see polymer work other browsers.